# How did first humans build tools?

Tags: prehistory, paleolithic

I'm referring this question in this way and tell me if I'm wrong:

The first humans were just surrounded by: rocks, trees, plants, water, sand, animals, fruits. So how just with hands, mouth, feet could they do for example a **knife**? They would need to take wood but the trees are too heavy for taking from there...

Comment: They could grind stones down to a sharp edge to make a blade. That said, this is not really a history question per se.

Comment: Obviously it's a history question, it happened in the past.

Comment: It happened in the **pre**-historical past.

Comment: It's still history. History is the study of the past.

Comment: @PichiWuana history is generally understood to be the analysis of the recorded past. Pre-history is distinct and involves different techniques.  Archaeology uses a totally different body of technology, skills, knowledge and practice to study pre-history. The answer to your question may be found by researching [Knapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapping)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That people generally understood something doesn't mean they are right. History is the study of the past, usually the past of the humans. Pre-history is the study of the past that isn't recorded, it still studies the past. Then there is **recorded history**. There is **history** that isn't part of the *recorded history*.

Comment: Wonderful, so should we leave this question undebated, because there is no prehistory / sociology stack, and your narrow defititions don't allow it to be discussed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our closest genetic relative, [the chimpanzees](http://www.janegoodall.org/chimp-central-toolmakers), have been observed to fashion themselves tools. That link even has a video showing one doing it, if you are interested in the process.

So most likely this is a behavior that was shared by our common ape ancestor over 7 million years ago. The only real tool innovation early man initially brought to the table (or at least the only surviving one in the fossil record) is that he seemed to be really into creating rock tools with chipping. Currently the oldest known examples [are from about 3.3 million years ago](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/oldest-known-stone-tools-unearthed-kenya-180955341/?no-ist).

Chimps and bonobos will *use* stone tools, but they haven't been observed systematically setting out to make themselves better stone tools by chipping off bit of stone. They will improve sticks to make tools, but not rocks (that we've seen).

Considering our species' lofty self-image, it doesn't seem like such a huge step to me.

Comment: Really interesting your answer, but I'm asking about how did they take wood from big trees and sharp them.

Comment: You make an edge on a suitable stone by chipping/working with another stone. Now you have an edge, a stone blade if you like, which you use as a tool to do other things, like skinning prey, cutting meat working wood, ... and making other tools.